# How to activate a feature only in powershell

Tags: 2010, features

I am trying to do this but cant find how

Update-SPSolution –Identity Teams.HomeWebTemplate.wsp –LiteralPath "D:\xx\bin\Debug\xxx.wsp" –GacDeployment

Get-SPFeature –Identity "xxx Links Feature" –Site http://xxxx/

it says
Cannot find an Enabled Feature object with Path or Id.  How can I know the id or the good name?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use following command to enable the feature:

```
Enable-SPFeature FeatureFolderName -Url http://server/site/subsite
```

For upgrading FEATURE using powershell, see this excellent article: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/08/feature-upgrade-part-5-using-powershell.html

Comment: what about if I want to upgrade a feature that I just upgraded its solution?

Comment: Check my updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/developing-web-parts-for-sharepoint-2010/
this should help you.. 
if you want it more precise look here: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx